# Error al llamar a método que se encuentra dentro de mi web service

Tags: java, hibernate

tengo el siguiente inconveniente,

Estoy tratando de conentarme a un método que se encuentra de un web service el mismo que tiene acceso a la base de datos pero a momento de crear la ruta se me presenta el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

Método desde donde formo la url:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/document_xml/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public ResponseEntity<DocumentXml> update(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @PathVariable("id") int id, 
        @RequestBody DocumentXml documentXml)
{
    System.out.println("Actualizar estado de documento: " + id);
    if(!UtilsService.readFileAllProperty(UtilsService.ABSOLUTE_PATH_FILE_PROPERTIES))
        return null;

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = auth.getName();
    System.out.println("username1: " + username);

    // Obtener el URL del WebService EQhatu
    String url = UtilsService.VALUE_WEBSERVICE_EQHATU;
    if(!url.substring(url.length()-1, url.length()).equalsIgnoreCase("/")){
        url = url + "/";
    }
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String res = restTemplate.postForObject(url + "document_xml_state"+id, documentXml, String.class);
    return new ResponseEntity<DocumentXml>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Método a donde debería llegar:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/document_xml_state", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public ResponseEntity<DocumentXml> update(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody DocumentXml documentXml){
        return new ResponseEntity<DocumentXml>(documentXmlDAO.save(documentXml), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Cuál sería la razón por la cual la url se escuentra mal formada? Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error 404 que ves en el log indica que el servidor al que estás llamando no encuentra lo que le estas pidiendo.

Creo que tienes un par que ajustar:

En el request mapping del método al que llamas, te falta añadir el parámetro en el path:
Puedes probar con `@RequestMapping(value="/document_xml_state/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST )`

A la hora de llamar a este metodo con el RestTemplate, añade la barra "/" entre el nombre del método y el id del documento. Quedaría así: `String res = restTemplate.postForObject(url + "document_xml_state/"+id, documentXml, String.class)`

Además, te recomiendo que antes de ejecutar la llamada muestres en el log la URL que formas para verificar que está correcta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, se resolvió mi problema :)